# LWC: @wire getListUi undocumented attribute "q" (query)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using an "getListUi" to get records from the list view. Now I have noticed that Visual Studio Code editors code assist displays some strange information about this interface: **"q"** - *query the current list view.*

[image]

I found this undocumented and unfortunately unavailable feature extreme usefull since I want to implement a list view search function...

Do you know whether this attribute will be implemented by salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can also pass the parameters listed in this Request Parameters table.

Which links to the [UI Api Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_list_views_object.htm#request_parameters) which lists the q parameter - so i would assume it is already supported (and documented). If it is not working its either a bug or there is an other issue i guess